# Splitting a Panda Column based on character count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, split

I have a pandas dataframe which includes the below date column with more than thousand raw of below format [YearMonth]

```
Date:
_____
201801
201802
201910
```

How can i split them so 2018 in one and month is n an other column. I tried splitstr but hard to get the count setting right.

Appreciate your help

Comment: What do you need to do with this data? It may be beneficial to convert them to a `datetime` with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `to_datetime` then using `dt` to access the `year` , `month` etc

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y%m')
df['Year']=s.dt.year
df['Month']=s.dt.month
df
     Date  Year  Month
0  201801  2018      1
1  201802  2018      2
2  201910  2019     10
```